# In php, how can I write variables expression?

Tags: php, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I received 'lang1', 'subject' variables.
And I want to write 2 varibles in file name as like below code.

```
  <?php
   $subject=$_POST['subject'];
   $lang1=$_POST['lang1'];

    $xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load("ds_'.$lang1.'_'.$subject.'.xml");
```

Last programming phrase is something wrong.
Please correct that.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: remove the special character...

Comment: You've got a mix of double and single quotes.  Change singles to doubles and it should work.  But loading a file based on user-submitted variables is a big security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because you are mixing up your quotes. If you start a string with double quotes you need to close the string with double quotes as well.

```
$xmlDoc->load("ds_".$lang1."_".$subject.".xml");
```

or

```
$xmlDoc->load('ds_'.$lang1.'_'.$subject.'.xml');
```

or

```
$xmlDoc->load("ds_{$lang1}_{$subject}.xml");
```